# I'm trying to get a blue-only colorWipe/rainbowCycle on an LED strip with an arduino uno and I'm having trouble

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I'm building a cosplay prop and want to use animated LEDs. I can get strandtest_wheel working and every pixel can display every colour, so I know it's not a physical problem with the LED strip.

When I try to run a rainbow cycle, the pixels transition smoothly but if I try to edit the colours of the color wipe or the rainbow cycle, the LED strip acts weirdly.

Instead of turning off all green and red light and only filling the strip with only blue, the color wipe command will fill the lights blue-red-green in sequence. The rainbow cycle command will also use all colours instead of just blue.

According to a guide I'm using (KamuiCosplay tutorial on animated lights), this should fill the strip with blue light & then rainbow cycle through blue colours.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.setBrightness(1);
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  //colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 10); // Red
  //colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 10); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 10); // Blue
  //colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW

  //theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50); // White
  //theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  //theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50); // Blue

  //rainbow(20);
  rainbowCycle(10);
  //theaterChaseRainbow(10);
}

// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
// The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(0, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, 0, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[Here's what the LED looks like when it's running rainbowCycle](https://imgur.com/gallery/KaQInCi)

This is my first time using an arduino so any & all help is appreciated :)